# Symfony2: How to set default locale and case insensitive translation

Tags: php, symfony, translation, locale, multilingual

I am just starting using symfony2 and facing some difficulty need helps from expert like you guys.

**Question 1: How to set the default locale and fallback locale so that people try to hit something like www.example.com/home or www.example.com/fr/home (not supported locale) will redirect to www.example.com/cn/home?**

I have read a lot from symfony2 document (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) and also searching on google but I still can't make it works. Not only default locale not working, the fallback locale also not working. For example, when user try to enter www.example.com/fr/home which is not supported by my app, it supposes to redirect the user to www.example.com/cn/home but it fails to do so.

I try to clear cache also but it seem like not working.

**Question 2: How to match the translation key in case insensitive?**

For example, in my translation file ("message.cn.yml") contains

```
Welcome: 欢迎
```

So in my twig template, I use {{ '**Welcome**' | trans }} it will help me convert to 欢迎 but when I use {{ '**welcome**' | trans }} it will not convert. Is there any ways to make it to case insensitive so I do not need to purposely add in the key "**welcome**: 欢迎" to the message.cn.yml file.

Your help and suggestion is very much appreciated. Thank you.

**Below are my app files for your reference:**

**Translations file:**

[image]

**Parameters file:**

[image]

**Config file:**

[image]

**Routing file in the particular bundle("Acme/DemoBundle"):**

[image]

**Twig file:**

[image]

Here is the result when I hit

1. localhost/locale/web/app_dev.php/

[image]

2. localhost/locale/web/app_dev.php/en

[image]

3. localhost/locale/web/app_dev.php/cn

[image]

4. localhost/locale/web/app_dev.php/fr

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set locale for a request:

```
 $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->setLocale($locale);
```

and you can set locale per request using a request listener:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types

for your second question you can add conversion to lower case:

```
   {{ 'WELCOME'|lower | translate}}
```

or you can create your own customized twig extension that is doing the translation and other stuff in between:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html